# SICP: I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity of the Fibonacci algorithim

Tags: algorithm, math, scheme, time-complexity, fibonacci

I'm reading through SICP. It's my first introduction to computer science.

The book presents the Fibonacci algorithm below:

```lisp
(define (fib n)
  (cond 
    ((= n 0) 0)
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (else (+ (fib (- n 1)) 
             (fib (- n 2))))))
```

The book mentions that the space this algorithm takes up is *(n)* and the time it takes is *(φ<sup>n</sup>)*. I understand the space complexity since it is the max depth of a tree, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how the time complexity is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write down how much time it takes in each case (1 is constant),

```
T(0) = 1
T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

you see that it is exactly the same as the Fibonacci numbers.
And as the text (almost) says, Fib(n) is (φ<sup>n</sup>).

Comment: where φ = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2? But that is the approximate size of the fib(n), not the complexity of computing it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk If you take f(10) and use the substitution model you'll end up with a line adding 1's together f(10) times. Thus the complexity of `fib(n)` is `O(fib(n))`